# Exporting ERwin models to XML or .erwin files programmatically

Tags: api, erwin

I have a requirement to programmatically export models in ERwin data modeler. The exported files could be saved in a directory (on server or local machine). We also want the process to export only the models that were changed after previous export.

Anybody know how to do that?

Thanks in advance,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

The Erwin API can be used to programatically access the model.

you can write a program to step through the model, extract and format the information you want to export.

One of the model properties is the date the model was last updated.  If your export program saves the date that it was last run, you could compare the 2.